# Add and delete a key value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Const data = [{
      Name1:{
             Name:"",
             Grade:"",
             Class:""
             },
       Name2:{
             Name:"",
             Grade:"",
             Class:""
             }
}]
```

I am having this type of data can any one please help me how to insert a new key value pair dynamically ie the Name1 the "1" should be dynamically generated based length  and for  delete particular key value pair I can pass index

Comment: Without having more info its hard to say, but you can use `data[0][\`Name${iterator}\`] = {}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple matter of knowing how to manipulate your data. Given the way you structured your data inside of an array with a single bigger object, that's how I managed to do it.

```js
const addData = (array, value) => {
  const key = "Name" + (Object.keys(array[0]).length + 1);
  const obj = array[0];
  obj[key] = value;
  
  return obj
}

const deleteData = (array, key) => {
    const obj = array[0];
  delete obj[key];
  
  return obj;
}
```

Starting with the simpler function, `deleteData()`, what we do here is get the array and the object key we want to wipe. The object is assigned to a new variable so we can manipulate it directly, and then we use `key` to delete the property from the object.

Now, for `addData()`, that a little trickier. For the `key` variable, we have to get the number of properties the object already has, and then add one. I did this by using `Object.keys()`, that returns an array with the keys and then using its `length` property. After that, it's not so different from `deleteData()`. It's just a matter of assigning the object to a variable (`const obj = array[0];`) and then adding the new property (`obj[key] = value;`). And, of course, we must return the result in the end.

I hope this has been helpful :)